# SpamAssasin: Custom rules are not implemented, what could be the reason?

Tags: spamassassin

I am trying to add new custom rules for spamassassin but my rules are not being implemented. I've added rules to /etc/spamassasssin/local.cf:

```
# CHECKING RULES FROM EMAIL

score NO_RELAYS 0
score MISSING_HEADERS 0
score MISSING_MID 0
score MISSING_SUBJECT 0
score NO_RECEIVED 0
score MISSING_DATE 0
score NO_HEADERS_MESSAGE 0

# ACTIVE RULES FOR FULL TEXT CHECK


full NO_VIOXX /vioxx/i
score NO_VIOXX 10
```

I try to execute `spamassassin --lint -D` and here is result:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eRAXeORydJwI7RK1Qdj0LPAcRIEct3vm9o4D9Wy7Z7U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What in the heck is `full` ?

Comment: It is full message pattern test. http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html